# How to edit configuration.nix via text editor?

Tags: nix

the only way i can edit `configuration.nix` is via the terminal.

The root user owns configuration.nix and my user does not have write access. Therefore, when i try to edit via a GUI like `Kate` i get a `permission denied` error.

Does anyone know how to edit the configuration file via a text editor gui?

P.S I tried chmod and it did not work.

Comment: This isn't a Nix-specific question (or a software-development-specific one either). You'd have the same problem, with the same solutions, trying to edit _any_ root-owned file that isn't world-writable, including on systems that don't run Nix or NixOS at all. This would thus be better placed on [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: (Also, _don't_ try chmod; making sensitive files world-writable is basically throwing away your system's security -- if you _were_ successful at making your configuration world-writable, you could never trust the machine again, because you could never know that someone hadn't used the time period when that writability existed to slip a rootkit in, and then removed it from the source once it was active)

Comment: ...see the classic paper [Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rdriley/487/papers/Thompson_1984_ReflectionsonTrustingTrust.pdf); just as that paper proposes a trojaned compiler that inserts a vulnerability whenever it compiles either itself or a specific network service, one could also temporarily insert a trojaned copy of Nix via the configuration, _and rely on that copy to propagate itself even when a known-good/trusted configuration is reintroduced_.

Comment: (Granted, the way Nix works makes it easier to catch that sort of thing than it would be in more conventional distros, but still, you're throwing away a _huge_ amount of security whenever you do `chmod 777`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is helpful to see the bigger picture, thanks for the additional context

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your GUI text editor with root permissions. One way to do it is to use `sudoedit` with the variable `SUDO_EDITOR` set to your GUI text editor:

```
env SUDO_EDITOR="<path to editor>" sudoedit /etc/nix/configuration.nix
```

As an example, you can set `SUDO_EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit`.

You could also use graphical editors dedicated to edit `configuration.nix`. You may find information on them in the [NixOS configuration editors](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_configuration_editors) wiki page.

---

As an alternative, the wiki page suggests taking permissions of `configuration.nix` and moving it to your home:

```
mkdir ~/etc
sudo mv /etc/nixos ~/etc/
sudo chown -R $(id -un):users ~/etc/nixos
sudo ln -s ~/etc/nixos /etc/
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a really simple workaround which also allows easy version control of your configuration:

1. Move the configuration to a directory under your home directory: `sudo mv /etc/nixos/configuration.nix ~/my-configuration/` (or similar)
2. Create a symbolic link at the original path referring back to the new path: `sudo ln -s "${HOME}/my-configuration/configuration.nix" /etc/nixos/configuration.nix`

Comment: While this works a proper way to move the NixOS configuration is to set `nix.nixPath` and include the location to `nixos-config` there; after switching to the new configuration using `-I`, then the new location will be remembered for any future invocations of the switch command. More details about this can be found at https://discourse.nixos.org/t/where-do-people-keep-their-configuration-nix/11044?u=zzantares